# QuickSort on a Single Structure. Doesn't work correctly

Tags: c, quicksort

I am trying to implement QuickSort in C on this structure:

```
typedef struct ConfigList{
    long **pathid;
    float *sort_coeff;
    int configsize;
    long num_total;
} ConfigList;
```

The QuickSort Function I wrote is shown below:

```
void QuickSort_ConfigList(ConfigList *CL,int num, int start)
{
    if(num>1)
    {
        long *temp_pathid;
        float temp_varscoeff;
        int k;
        float pivot = CL->sort_coeff[num/2];
        int left = start;
        int right = start+num-1;
        while(left<=right)
        {
            if(CL->sort_coeff[left] < pivot)
            {
                left++;
                continue;
            }
            if(CL->sort_coeff[right] > pivot)
            {
                right--;
                continue;
            }
            temp_pathid = CL->pathid[left];
            CL->pathid[left] = CL->pathid[right];
            CL->pathid[right] = temp_pathid;
            temp_varscoeff = CL->sort_coeff[left];
            CL->sort_coeff[left++] = CL->sort_coeff[right];
            CL->sort_coeff[right--] = temp_varscoeff;
        }
        QuickSort_ConfigList(CL,right+1,0);
        QuickSort_ConfigList(CL,num-left,left);
    }
}
```

I doesn't seem to work properly and I believe that I am unable to spot a simple error because I don't know QuickSort very well. Two sample outputs are shown below (Note: This simply prints the ConfigList->sort_coeff to the console):

**Here it works fine!**

```
    Sort_Coeff = 1.250000
    Sort_Coeff = 1.250000
    Sort_Coeff = 1.277778
    Sort_Coeff = 1.416667
    Sort_Coeff = 1.416667
```

**Here it fails!**

```
    Sort_Coeff = 0.800000
    Sort_Coeff = 0.861111
    Sort_Coeff = 0.888889
    Sort_Coeff = 0.888889
    Sort_Coeff = 1.083333
    Sort_Coeff = 1.055556
    Sort_Coeff = 1.027778
    Sort_Coeff = 1.138889
    Sort_Coeff = 1.138889
    Sort_Coeff = 0.944444
```

It seems to be a slight error which I cannot spot, but unfortunately I haven't been able to find any implementation which can act on a single structure.

Comment: It would probably help to see the data you populate into your structure and the call to your function.  Also, the `pathid` seems to be tangential to your problem (so an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) would omit it).  Similarly, both `config_size` and `num_total` are not referenced; they should be omitted.  This would allow you to simplify your sort to a plain sort of an array of `float`, which you can debug more easily.  Then you can add the extra bits and pieces as you go.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I felt the whole code would be of less interest. Those variables are being used elsewhere, hence I cannot populate the structure without them as of now.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I utilized a code from the rosettastone archives, so I was pretty sure it should work on a float array. It seems to more or less work here as well. The pathids are later used to search into another structure in order to gather more information. If it helps, the intended size of the num_total which is the same as num is 50000.

Comment: Yes, you can.  For example, `float a1[] = { 1.250000, 1.250000, 1.277778, 1.416667, 1.416667 };` and `QuickSort_FloatList(a1, 5, 0);`, and `float a2[] = { 0.800000, 0.861111, 0.888889, 0.888889, 1.083333, 1.055556, 1.027778, 1.138889, 1.138889, 0.944444 };` and `QuickSort_FloatList(a2, 10, 0);` where the revised, simplified sort is called `QuickSort_FloatList` because it sorts an array of `float` values.

Comment: @AdityaSomani but you *can* sort just the floats for now without the other extraneous data. If that works, then your problem is *very likely* in the part you took out; not your sorting algorithm. Isolation is numero uno when it comes to stepwise debugging.

Comment: @AdityaSomani Can you show the *initial* invoke from your main program where you invoke `QuickSort_ConfigList`? I'm curious what number is used for the size in the initial call. Is it the `num_total` member or the `configsize` member ?

Comment: @WhozCraig num_total member with a size = 50000. It's basically a single line with inputs `configlist,configlist->num_total,0`.

Comment: @AdityaSomani yeah, ok. updated the answer below. The last edit is the one you want to see. It uses a wrapper to suck data out of the single parameter `cl`, sending the two arrays side-by-side through the inner sort function. Peruse it, it should be obvious how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm nearly certain it is your sequence length handling that is the issue, and although I have not taken the time to analyze it fully yet, in the interest of getting you up and running, consider the following, which eliminates the "start" point parameter in favor of a simple sequence length and pointer math for the recursive calls:

**QuickSorting Side-By-Side Arrays**

Sending a secondary array that needs identical swapping should be doable. as discussed in-comment, I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
typedef struct ConfigList
{
    long **pathid;
    float *sort_coeff;
    int configsize;
    long num_total;
} ConfigList;

void QuickSort_ConfigListData(float *coeffs, long** pathids, size_t len)
{
    if (len < 2)
        return;

    float temp_varscoeff;
    long *temp_pathids;

    float pivot = coeffs[len/2];
    size_t left = 0;
    size_t right = len-1;

    while(left<right)
    {
        if (coeffs[left] < pivot)
        {
            ++left;
            continue;
        }

        if (coeffs[right] > pivot)
        {
            --right;
            continue;
        }

        // swap pathids pointers
        temp_pathids = pathids[left];
        pathids[left] = pathids[right];
        pathids[right] = temp_pathids;

        // swap floats
        temp_varscoeff = coeffs[left];
        coeffs[left++] = coeffs[right];
        coeffs[right--] = temp_varscoeff;
    }
    QuickSort_ConfigListData(coeffs, pathids, right);
    QuickSort_ConfigListData(coeffs+left, pathids+left, len - left);
}

void QuickSort_ConfigList(ConfigList* cl)
{
    QuickSort_ConfigListData(cl->sort_coeff, cl->pathid, cl->num_total);
}
```

---

**Cheatinng with `qsort()`**

Albeit more memory intensive (and by that I mean roughly 1.2MB, which is so cheap these days i'm pretty sure my cat drops more than that every morning in its litter box), you can forego your own sorting algorithm and just do this:

```
// used for sorting with qsort
struct config_s
{
    long *pathid;
    float coeef;
};

// comparator for qsort
int cmp_config_s(const void *arg1, const void* arg2)
{
    struct config_s const* lhs = arg1;
    struct config_s const *rhs = arg2;
    return (lhs->coeff < rhs->coeff) ? -1 : (rhs->coeff < lhs->coeff);
}

void QuickSort_ConfigList(Configlist* cl)
{
    struct config_s *ar = NULL;
    long i=0;

    if (cl->num_total < 2)
        return;

    // build sort-bed
    ar = malloc(cl->num_total * sizeof(*ar));
    for (i=0; i<cl->num_total; ++i)
    {
        ar[i].coeef = cl->sort_coeff[i];
        ar[i].pathid = cl->pathid[i]
    }

    // fire qsort
    qsort(ar, cl->num_total, sizeof(*ar), cmp_config_s);

    // rewrite as sorted
    for (i=0; i<cl->num_total; ++i)
    {
        cl->sort_coeff[i] = ar[i].coeef;
        cl->pathid[i] = ar[i].pathid;
    }
    free(ar);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I did not think this could be done with len. I shall try the same!

Comment: @AdityaSomani If you want to see the sweep method I can show that as well. its so simple its almost laughable, but hopefully this gets you rocking regardless.

Comment: As y'all mentioned, I optimized that array assigment. It seems to work.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'd more than appreciate it!! :D

Comment: @WhozCraig Har Har, I remember why I didn't use this. You can *divide* arrays and make them smaller. How do I do this with a structure like this. :(

Comment: @AdityaSomani you would still do it, but it you would need an additional parameter that is only used for swapping your dynamic pointer lists. I.e. it isn't part of the comparison. Since the sizes are the same (my assumption, but you can validate that), it is still plausible. Of course, hunting the error down in your sizing logic would be just as easy/hard, I imagine.

Comment: @WhozCraig Umm. I'm not sure I can understand what you mean. Can you dumb it down a little bit? Sorry >_<

Comment: @AdityaSomani Ok. updated (see bottom edit). Hopefully that shows what I was talking about.

Comment: @WhozCraig So, when I translate this code for the structure, I can pass in the structure to the swap function and pass in len/2 and len-1 as indices for it right?

Comment: Belay in-place-sweep for a minute and see the **Edit** at the end of the post. That was what I was talking about. You just call `QuickSort_ConfigList(cl);` where `cl` is your config-list structure address. If the `num_total` member is as you say it is, this will do what you want, I'm nearly certain of it.

Comment: @One last question, should the in-sweep method be faster than the other standard method?

Comment: @AdityaSomani they're both NlogN. It is conceivable the squeeze algorithm will have fewer *swaps* depending on the initial ordering of the data, but both will have roughly the same number of comparisons, however.

Comment: @WhozCraig Should that have a <= instead of the < where the comparison between left < right is being made?

Comment: @AdityaSomani if you're talking about the last algorithm, no. Once left and right are equal no swap is needed. It is conceivable a let or right is found to need swapping without a mate, but when that happens the element ends up swapping with itself. It should be correct as presented. Funny thing, for all this code it would have been faster to load up a set of custom structs with pointers into your lists, sort the structs using qsort, then rewrite the lists with the results. Odds are you'd be sleeping by now if we went that route. =P

Answer (score 2):

Here is an SSCCE that guts your algorithm and sorts an array of `float` values.  It works on both test data sets:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void QuickSort_FloatList(float *data, int num, int start)
{
    if (num > 1)
    {
        float pivot = data[num / 2];
        int left = start;
        int right = start + num - 1;
        while (left <= right)
        {
            if (data[left] < pivot)
            {
                left++;
                continue;
            }
            if (data[right] > pivot)
            {
                right--;
                continue;
            }
            float temp_varscoeff = data[left];
            data[left++] = data[right];
            data[right--] = temp_varscoeff;
        }
        QuickSort_FloatList(data, right + 1, 0);
        QuickSort_FloatList(data, num - left, left);
    }
}

static void dump_array(const char *tag, float *data, int num)
{
    printf("%s (%d):\n", tag, num);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        printf(" %g", data[i]);
        if (num % 8 == 7)
            putchar('\n');
    }
    if (num % 8 != 0)
        putchar('\n');
}

static void check_sorted(float *data, int num)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (data[i-1] > data[i])
            printf("Out of order: [%d] = %g; [%d] = %g\n", i-1, data[i-1], i, data[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    float a1[] = { 1.250000, 1.250000, 1.277778, 1.416667, 1.416667 };
    dump_array("Before A1", a1, 5);
    QuickSort_FloatList(a1, 5, 0);
    dump_array("After  A1", a1, 5);
    check_sorted(a1, 5);
    float a2[] =
    {
        0.800000, 0.861111, 0.888889, 0.888889, 1.083333,
        1.055556, 1.027778, 1.138889, 1.138889, 0.944444
    };
    dump_array("Before A2", a2, 10);
    QuickSort_FloatList(a2, 10, 0);
    dump_array("After  A2", a2, 10);
    check_sorted(a2, 10);
}
```

Sample output:

```
Before A1 (5):
 1.25 1.25 1.27778 1.41667 1.41667
After  A1 (5):
 1.25 1.25 1.27778 1.41667 1.41667
Before A2 (10):
 0.8 0.861111 0.888889 0.888889 1.08333 1.05556 1.02778 1.13889 1.13889 0.944444
After  A2 (10):
 0.8 0.861111 0.888889 0.888889 0.944444 1.02778 1.05556 1.13889 1.13889 1.08333
Out of order: [8] = 1.13889; [9] = 1.08333
```

---

<s>This suggests (but is not conclusive proof) that the core sort is OK.</s>

This shows that there is a problem with the core sort.  That needs to be fixed before you adapt it to sort the more complex structure you have.  Note that using an automatic sort checker is a good idea; I cut a corner in the first version of this answer and didn't spot the problem eyeballing the results.

You might still have trouble stemming from the original code playing with the `pathid` array, but get the basic sort to work first.  Then it becomes crucial that you show us how you create and print the structure.

Note that one of the first things I did was create code to print the array.  It is a fundamental technique for debugging.  You should have a data structure dumper function that you can rely on to print valid data structures accurately.

Your code for swapping the pointers to the arrays of `long` seems more complex than necessary; you should be able to just swap the two pointers to the start of the arrays.  However, this is where it is crucial to know how you're creating your data structure.  There could be many differences between what I think you're doing and what you're actually doing.

Comment: OK; I can't see — I'm blind.  It's also why I should write a sort checker function!

Comment: .. or just used qsort. =P I think the problem is the sequence length handling.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Phew! Thanks! I was just checking into that, because I assure you that the pathid values should not matter. They are basically what this sorting coeff is being compiled in order to sort. I also wanted to optimize that array allocation. I'll try and do that as soon as this is fixed.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'll be more than happy to use QSort *iff* it works with that Structure. :)

Comment: Standard `qsort()` cannot readily be used to sort two parallel arrays, which is what you've got with this data structure.

Comment: @AdityaSomani nono, i didn't mean *you* use it; I mean *Jonathan* use it for validation =P

Comment: @WhozCraig Ahhhh I see. Sorry. ^_^

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I changed the code to reflect the optimization suggested by you. It is actually quite obvious but I got lost in the wilderness earlier when I tried to do it. You know one of those programming thoughts when you start to doubt yourself.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks a ton! It finally works now!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the problem:

```
       if(CL->sort_coeff[left] <= pivot)  /* Maybe it goes here.... */
        {
            if (left <= start) left++;    /* from the code.... */
            continue;
        }
        if(CL->sort_coeff[right] > pivot)  
        {
            right--;
            continue;
        }
```

Comment: I coded this based on this code. It doesn't mention it. :( I'll try it though! http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#C

Comment: Nope, that Seg Faults. :(

Comment: One of the many reasons I prefer the in-place left-to-right sweep algorithm for quicksort rather then the left/right collapsing squeeze algorithm. This never becomes an issue. Yeah, the in-place-sweep  has the potential for a few more iterations and swaps, but it is so damn simple to implement in comparison, I rarely find a need to use anything else.

Comment: @WhozCraig I need to sort an array of 100,000 :(

Comment: @AdityaSomani trivial no matter which quicksort you use, sweep, squeeze, 3-parition, or anything else. That number is anything but scary for quicksort.

Comment: I switched to <=, as per the cited algorithm.

Comment: @WhozCraig Is there any other method I can use for the fastest execution time. Earlier I was using bubble.

Comment: @Jim It seg faults when trying to assign the pivot. I'm not sure why even though the pivot is clearly inside the range. Also, array indices are suppose to truncate down right?

Comment: @Jim. Float comparison worked fine with bubble sort... Just take bloody 100 seconds to do 50,000 :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52809/discussion-between-aditya-somani-and-jim)